# How to separate paper from college block?

Tags: paper

I've always had issues with some college blocks not allowing the paper to be ripped off perfectly, since the tear line isn't thin enough.

Is there any trick I could use to never have [this issue](http://previews.123rf.com/images/hansjoergnisch/hansjoergnisch1110/hansjoergnisch111000008/11027531-checkered-sheet-of-paper-from-a-college-block-Stock-Photo.jpg) again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on how far the block is used, try to fold the paper on the tear line. Use your nail or the back of a pen / pencil.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a ruler or a rigid edge of a notebook to serve as a guide. Pressing the ruler on the tear line, then tear off the paper while pressing the ruler firmly onto the notebook. Your page will be torn off with a nice clean edge. An example of how to use a ruler to tear paper shown here:

[image]